# How to make scrollbar?

Tags: html, css

i'm new here. i create a table which can show the data from the database and create 1 more table to show the data which be selected. But the problem is if we just select few data it wont be a problem. but if select more than 100 data it can cause a layout problem.

and this my code...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function List(){
    var selectedProduct = ""; 
    var product = document.getElementById('product');
    var output ="";         
    var k = 0;  
    var name = new Array;
    var model = new Array;
    var unitprice = new Array;

        <?php foreach ($productPrices as $price): ?>
            name[k] = "<?php echo $price['Product']['txtname']; ?>";
            model[k] = "<?php echo $price['Product']['txtmodel']; ?>";

            k++;
        <?php endforeach; ?>

        k=0;
        for (var i = 0; i < product.length; i++) { 
                k = product.options[i].value;

            if (product.options[i].selected) {  
                output += '<tr>'+
                                '<td style="border-right: 0px; width:270px; text-align:center" id="ProductProduct'+k+'" name="data[Product][Product]['+k+']">'+name[i]+'</td>'+
                                '<td style="border-right: 0px; width:100px; text-align:left" id="ProductProduct'+k+'" name="data[Product][Product]['+k+']">'+model[i]+'</td>'+
                            '</tr>';    
            }
        } 
        output = '<table style="width:500px; border: 0px;">'+output+'</table>';         
        document.getElementById('productTable').innerHTML = output;
}                   
</script>

<table  cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="width:100%">
    <caption><div align="left">Peoduct Selection</div></caption>
    <tr>
        <th  style="width:25%"><font><div align="left">Select Product :</div></font>
                    <?php   echo $form->input('Product',array(
                            'label' => 'Select Products',
                            'options' => $products,
                            'id'=>'product',
                            'style'=>'width:250px;height:100px',
                            'selected' => $html->value('Product.Product'),
                            'onchange'=>'List();')); ?> </th>
        <th ><table>
            <tr>
                <th style="width:400px"><div align="center">Product Name</div></th>
                <th style="width:250px"><div align="center">Product Model</div></th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="4" ><span id="productTable"></td>
            </tr>
        </table></th>
    </tr>
    </table>
```

Can anyone help me solve this? thx..

Comment: Why did you change my retag? This question has nothing to do with php, but rather with your layout, therefor, its a HTML/CSS problem.

Comment: @x3ro - I'm guessing, but he probably did it by mistake, where he was already editing when your edit was submitted.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To solve this problem put the table tag in a "Div" tag and give the particular "height" to "Div" tag which you wanna give and give "style=overflow:auto" to DIV Tag. It will automatically show the scroll bar.

Comment: No offense, but this is _exactly_ what I've answered 4 hours ago... My answer was understandable, though.

Answer (score 8):

You can wrap whatever element that could get big, specify a height, and then setting the css "overflow" property to "scroll".

See the W3C's [tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/Css/pr_pos_overflow.asp) on CSS's `overflow` property.